# Array to array copying using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to copy some elements from one array to another and in a way it does work but it copies the whole array when the pointer only points to one element. This is the code:

```
char buffer[64], buffer1[2];
char* pointer;
strcpy(buffer, "Word");

pointer = buffer1; 
*pointer = buffer[0];
printf("%c\n", *pointer);

printf("%s\n", buffer1);
```

When I print *pointer to the console I get "W" but when I print buffer1 to the console I get "WÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌWord", how is that even possible? It can only take two elements?

Comment: You haven't null terminated `buffer1`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry I must have clicked "C" as a suggestion

Comment: Right well this is not how one writes C++! :)

Comment: @Praetorian Thank you it works now but could I ask why does not null terminating buffer1 give me "WÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌWord"?

Comment: The entire problem is that you failed to null-terminate the string in "buffer1". For example, `buffer1[1] = `'0';` => "W".

Comment: @user2387537 Nothing that it prints after the first `W` is guaranteed. It's just whatever happens to be in those memory locations. Lightness' answer provides a good explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how is that even possible? It can only take two elements?

Yeah, and those two elements were printed successfully.

However, since neither of those elements is a `'\0'`, `printf` had no idea that it had reached the end of your array (how was it to know?!) and kept reading from your computer's memory until it reached a `\0` somewhere.

> in a way it does work but it copies the whole array when the pointer only points to one element

Pointers only ever "point to one element"; when you use a `printf` formatter like `"%s"`, which is for a string, the language *has* to assume that said element has other elements next to it (say, in an array), and it'll keep incrementing the pointer and printing until it finds a `'\0'` to tell it to stop.

**In short, you overran the buffer.**

In C, ensure you leave enough room for a terminating NULL byte; in C++, use `std::string`:

```
const std::string buffer  = "Word";
const std::string buffer1 = buffer;

std::cout << buffer[0] << '\n' << buffer1 << '\n';
```